# Placement of "by the time" in "But by the time Pino had trudged down the mountain..."

Tags: phrase-usage

Doesn't this sentence seems odd to you?

> "But by the time Pino had trudged down the mountain to Madesimo and then back up to Motta, he was exhausted"

My question is about where "by the time" is used in the mentioned sentence. Shouldn't it be used at the beginning of the second clause rather than the first one?

Comment: Show your suggested re-writing.

Comment: Please put the question and the example in the body of the post. Use the title to describe the problem. Also, it's a good habit to explain _why_ you think something is wrong or should be changed, or include your research. This will help prevent close votes. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's poorly written, as another answerer has opined.

And **by the time** is right where it belongs.

> By the time I get to Phoenix, she'll be rising.

I believe that what you have in mind is this:

> Pino had trudged down the mountain to Madesimo and then back up to Motta. By **that** time, he was exhausted.

P.S. If you reverse the order of the clauses:

> Pino was exhausted **by the time** he had trudged down the mountain to Madesimo and then back up to Motta.

The compound clause *he had trudged ... and then [trudged] back up to Motta* complements **the time**, defining it.

In the earlier example with **by *that* time**, a complement clause does not define **time**; rather the time is defined via anaphoric reference to the preceding clause, ***that* time**.